# Existence of some sequence - convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let $X_n$ be any sequence of random variables. Find  a suequence of non-zero numbers $a_n$ such that $a_nX_n$ converges to $0$ in distribution.

Can someone give me a hint? - I stuck on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F_n$ be the distribution function of $|X_n|$, i.e., $F_n(x) = \mathbb P(|X_n| \le x) $.

Define $F_n^{-1}(y) = \inf\{x:F_n(x) \ge y\}$.
Let $a_n$ be such that
$$\frac 1 {a_n n} = F_n^{-1}(1-1/n).$$
Then
$$
\mathbb P \left\{|X_n| \ge \frac 1 {a_n n}\right\} \le \frac 1 n.
$$
In other words, $a_n X_n$ converges in probability to $0$, which implies that it also converges in distribution to $0$.

Comment: +1. Exercise: Adapt this exact idea to ensure almost sure convergence.